# Alignment and non-default floating point representation

Tags: python, string, format

For my work, I often check the content of some files before beginning to use them and I began to create ipython notebooks with the checks and some pretty prints to summarize what I get. For this I typically use `print` and `str.format` get ordered outputs or fixed number decimals in floats. What I can do is summarized here:

```
f = 32.4321413432
a = 34121
print('float {ff} and integer {ii}'.format(ff=f, i=i))
print('float {ff:.4f} and integer {ii:d}'.format(ff=f, ii=i))
print('float {ff:>20} and integer {ii:>10}'.format(ff=f, ii=i))
```

output

```
float 32.4321413432 and integer 34121
float 32.4321 and integer 34121
float        32.4321413432 and integer      34121
```

sometimes I would love to be able to set **together** alignment and number of decimal and get an output like this

```
float        32.4321 and integer      34121
```

I have tried a number of combinations of `.4f` and `>20` in `{ff:...}` but I get

> ValueError: Invalid conversion specification

Is what I want possible at all and if yes, how is the syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean like this?

```
f = 32.4321413432
i = 34121
print('float {ff:>20.4f} and integer {ii:>10}'.format(ff=f, ii=i))
```

which yields

```
float              32.4321 and integer      34121
```